# SQL Server 2008 Error logs missing

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

In managment studio there is a range of dates in Managment > SQL Server Logs that is missing. Where are these logs stored? Is there a way I can try to reload the missing logs if they are available somewhere?

Comment: If the log files were deleted, their contents can be found in the Registry as well.

Comment: Where in the registry would I find them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `sp_readerrorlog` in a new query window. This will read the latest SQL Server Error Log for you. In the first few lines you can get the location where the Error Logs are stored.

Comment: Thank you that did give me the location I was looking for. Just need to figure out a way to parse through these files and find out if the missing logs are here somewhere. Not sure what caused this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Where are they stored?  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log

How do you have their management configured?  In Mgt Studio, expand the Management folder, right click on SQL Server Logs, Configure.  Default is six and then they roll off.

Comment: I do not have the box checked to limit the number of error logs before they are recycled.
I am currently showing the current log plus 6 archive logs. 
In between the most recent archive log and the current log there is a 6 week gap of missing logs

Comment: I don't have a folder called log in this location
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008\MSSQL

Comment: Should be under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server unless moved.

Comment: Would this be it?
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20100727_173104

Answer (score 0):

Dont you have a backup. Restore it somewhere and get the logs backed up in a diffrent location and try to take them to your default location

Comment: We just set this server up a month ago and a backup is on the to-do list but it hasn't been done yet (Bad i know)

Comment: thats a terrible problem. Sorry I have no solution from my side